# Animate webview android

Tags: android, animation, layout, webview

I am trying to slide a webview to the side, revealing another webview underneath it. I want to support android 2.2 and up, so I had to use a library to support animation in the 3.0+ way. I used NineOldAndroids to handle Animations. This works great. But unfortunately, when the animate(mainView).x(px); finishes, on versions lower than 3.0, the hitboxes in the webview did not update their position. How do I force the layout to update so that all the button-hitboxes also shift with the webview?

EDIT: 
The way it looks right now is that I use NineOldAnroids library

`import static com.nineoldandroids.view.ViewPropertyAnimator.animate;`

And animate the x by a value of px (which is a float)

`animate(mainView).x(px)`

Now when I press a link on the animated webview, it doesn't work. When I press the link at the position where the webview used to be, it works. So clearly only the pixels of the webview have been moved, but not the actual layout. How do I tackle this problem?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Show use some code so we can try it out by ourselves.

Comment: @theomega I have, check the edited question. =)

Answer (score 0):

I have *no knowledge* about the library u have mentioned.I would just suggest u to use **Sliding Drawer**. Simply Because u want to show animation all u have to do is to add ur WebView inside the Sliding Drawer.All u have to do is to add **slidinganimationclose** for the 1st one and open the next accordingly.

Comment: I didn't know about the existance of this sliding drawer class. I will take a look and let you know if it works, thanks.

Comment: The sliding drawer hides something offscreen and shows it when dragging a slider. The functionality I need is comparable to the facebook app-menu button. I have two web views, a menu, and the main view on top. when I press the menu button inside the main view, the main view should slide to the right revealing the menu underneath. Is the sliding drawer capable of sliding existing fullscreen content to the side?